# Compute derivative of log-determinant of matrix with respect to a vector

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I have a problem to solve:

Firstly, I have totally $N$ observations $W_i\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times D}$, including $N_1$ positive class samples and $N_0$ negative class samples.

Then, there is an arbitrary vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^{D}$. I compute $W_i b\in\mathbb{R}^{D}$, and get $N$ vectors totally. Mean of the vectors can be computed as $$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{{{W}}_i}{{b}} = } {{\bar Wb}}.$$ With respect to all, positive and negative class samples, the mean vectors are $\bar Wb$, $\bar W_0b$, $\bar W_1b$.

Next, we also compute three empirical covariance matrices $S$, $S_0$, $S_1$, following the formula as below: $$\begin{array}{l}
{{S}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\left( {{{{W}}_i}{{b}} - {{\bar Wb}}} \right)} {\left( {{{{W}}_i}{{b}} - {{\bar Wb}}} \right)^T}\\
{\rm{ = }}\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\left( {{{{W}}_i} - {{\bar W}}} \right){{b}}{{{b}}^T}} {\left( {{{{W}}_i} - {{\bar W}}} \right)^T}
\end{array}.$$

Finally, we compute $$M = {\log}\frac{{det(S)}}{{\prod\limits_{class} {{{ {det({S}_{class})}}^{\frac{{{N_{class}}}}{N}}}} }},$$

My question is: how to compute $\frac{{\partial M}}{{\partial b}}$.

I have already done some tests. It is easy to prove that $M$ doesn't change when $b$ is multiplied by a constant. So I sampled some points $b$ on the unit sphere (3 dimensions for easier to visualization), calculate $M$, and get [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRNvQ.png)

It seems that $M$ is a constant with respect to arbitrary $b$, if my code is right.

I would like to know why it is happen.

This problem may take some patience to solve, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define 
$$\eqalign{
x_k &= W_kb \quad
&X = \left[\matrix{x_1&x_2 \ldots x_n}\right] \\
e_k &\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times 1}
\quad &\big({\rm standard\, basis\, vectors}\big) \\
J &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^ne_ie_k^T 
\quad &\big({\rm all\, ones\, matrix}\big) \\
C &= I-\tfrac{1}{n}J
\quad &\big({\rm centering\, matrix}\big) \\
S &= \tfrac{1}{n}XCX^T
\quad &\big({\rm covariance\, matrix}\big) \\
\lambda &= n\log\det S \\
}$$
Assume that the observations are arranged such that the two classes are simple contiguous block-partitions $(n=n_1+n_2)$ of the above matrices. 
$$\eqalign{
X_1 &= X\left[\matrix{I_1\\0}\right] = 
XP_1 &= \left[\matrix{x_1\ldots x_{n_1}}\right] \\
X_2 &= X\left[\matrix{0\\I_2}\right] = 
XP_2 &= \left[\matrix{x_{n_1+1}\ldots x_{n}}\right] \\
X &= X\left[\matrix{I_1&0\\0&I_2}\right] &=\left[\matrix{x_1\ldots x_{n_1}&x_{n_1+1}\ldots x_n}\right]\\
C_1 &= I_1-\tfrac{1}{n_1}J_1,\qquad
&C_2 = I_2-\tfrac{1}{n_2}J_2 \\
S_1 &= \tfrac{1}{n_1}X_1C_1X_1^T,\qquad 
&S_2 = \tfrac{1}{n_2}X_2C_2X_2^T \\
\lambda_1 &= n_1\log\det S_1,\qquad
&\lambda_2 = n_2\log\det S_2 \\
}$$
Write the function of interest in terms of these new variables.

Then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
M &= \frac{1}{n}(\lambda - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2) \\
n\,dM
 &= d\lambda - d\lambda_1 - d\lambda_2 \\
 &= (nS^{-1}:dS) - (n_1S_1^{-1}:dS_1) - (n_2S_2^{-1}:dS_2) \\
 &= S^{-1}:2\operatorname{Sym}(dX\,CX^T) - (\ldots) \\
 &= 2S^{-1}XC:dX - (\ldots) \\
dM
 &= \frac{2}{n}\left(
  S^{-1}XC:dX - S_1^{-1}X_1C_1:dX_1 - S_2^{-1}X_2C_2:dX_2 
\right)\\
 &= \frac{2}{n}\left(
  S^{-1}XC:dX - S_1^{-1}XP_1C_1:dX\,P_1 - S_2^{-1}XP_2C_2:dX\,P_2 
\right)\\
 &= \frac{2}{n}\left(
  S^{-1}XC - S_1^{-1}XP_1C_1P_1^T - S_2^{-1}XP_2C_2P_2^T 
\right):dX\\
&= A:dX \\
}$$
At this point, notice that $X$ can be expanded as a sum, and substituted
$$\eqalign{
 X &= \sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k^T = \sum_{k=1}^nW_kbe_k^T \\
dX &= \sum_{k=1}^nW_k\,db\,e_k^T \\
dM &= A:\sum_{k=1}^nW_k\,db\,e_k^T \\
   &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^nW_k^TAe_k\right):db \\
\frac{\partial M}{\partial b} &= \sum_{k=1}^nW_k^TAe_k \\
}$$
Given this expression for the gradient, it doesn't *appear* to be equal to zero.

Perhaps if the sum is expanded out and simplified, everything will cancel?

Note that a colon is used in some of the steps above as a product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TB) 
}$$
The Sym operation was also used at one point
$$\operatorname{Sym}(A) = \frac{A+A^T}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your patient reply. But I think the covariance matrix $S = \frac{1}{n}XC{X^T}$ should be $S = \frac{1}{n}XC{\left( {XC} \right)^T}$. $XC = \left[ {{x_1} - \bar x\;\;{x_2} - \bar x\; \cdots \;{x_n} - \bar x} \right].$

Comment: True, but the Centering Matrix has lots of cool properties, e.g. $C^2=C=C^T$. So your expression reduces to the one given above.

Comment: It's amazing! I am new to matrix calculus, do you have some suggested books about that?

Comment: The standard text is Magnus and Neudecker's "_Matrix Differential Calculus_"; I also like Hjorungnes's "_Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_"; there's also an online PDF file titled "_The Matrix Cookbook_" compiled by Petersen and Pedersen.

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

Comment: By coding, the expression for the gradient seems to be equal to zero.

Comment: @JarvisYang I updated the answer. There's got to be an easier way to prove this that I'm missing.

Comment: I'm sorry for missing an important condition. $W_k$ should be a real symmetric matrix. About "$x_k = W_kb \quad\implies\quad W_k = \frac{Xe_kb^T}{\|b\|^2}$", ${\hat W_k} = \frac{{X{e_k}{b^T}}}{{b{^2}}}$ can imply $x_k = \hat W_kb$, but I am not sure it can be reversed. Even though $W_k$ is symmetric, we cannot actually solve for $W_k$ given $x_k$ and $b$.

Comment: After some numerical analysis under different conditions ($W_k$ is symmetric or not, it's size, it's diagonal elements are zero or not), the gradient is not always equals to zero. Under certain conditions, the equation sets up. To fully understand the results may take a lot of efforts, so this question should be closed now. Thank you anyway!